# p2p voip via flash?

Tags: flash, adobe, p2p, voip

Is there any way to implement voice chat between two peers directly (without server calls, except for some initial http requests) using Flash (or maybe Java, but flash is prefered)?
Users are supposed to open voice chat in browser.
What are the keywords to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be something like that in the latest Flash Player: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/features/

> Peer-assisted networking ENHANCED
>
> Protect media delivery through the
>   encrypted Real Time Media Flow
>   Protocol (RTMFP) — a more secure
>   UDP-based network transport
>   alternative to RTMP over TCP. Support
>   for RTMFP groups allows clients to
>   easily participate with other clients
>   in a network in order to share the
>   transport of media and communications
>   without maintaining a connection to
>   every peer in the group.
>   Application-level multicast provides
>   one-to-many (or a-few-to-many)
>   streaming of continuous live video and
>   audio or live video chat using RTMFP
>   groups. Peer-assisted networking is
>   available using Flash Media Server 4.

As you can see though, you might have to use FMS4 for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, have look at [Adobe Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/).